# Number of generators of a subgroup of a finite simple group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group $G$ we denote $d(G)$ the minimal size of a set of generators of $G$. We define  $D(G) = \max( d(H) \mid H\leq G)$.

Let $S$ be a finite simple group. Are there `good' bounds on $D(S)$ in terms of the size of $S$?

Comment: Every finite group $G$ embeds into $A_n$ for some $n>4$. This gives some (not very good) bound for $D(S)$. 

Comment: $\log_2 |S|$ is an easy upper bound. I would be surprised if the large elementary abelian groups of rank about $n/2$ inside the alternating groups $A_n$ didn't provide the asymptotic maximum.

Comment: @Duglas: You are probably right that the Abelian subgroups have maximal rank, but perhaps one should consider groups of Lie type instead of $A_n$. 

Comment: No it seems that $A_n$ is better asymptotically ($n!$ vs $q^{n^2}$).

Comment: by mistake I rolled back, and can't find how to undo. HELP!!!

Comment: Mail the administrators. Alternatively, check the edit list (click on the hours ago) and see if you can rollback to a desired version. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.25

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By a Theorem of R. Guralnick and A. Lucchini (see MR1015993 and MR 1023965),(which does require the classification of finite simple groups)  the minimum number of generators for a finite group $G$ can exceed by at most one the maximum (over all its Sylow subgroups $P$) of the minimum number of generators of $P$. It follows that the value of $D(G)$ is between $d(H)$ and $d(H)+1$ for some $p$-subgroup $H$ of $G.$ Thus for a finite simple group $S,$ the question does essentially come down to bounding the minimum number of generators of subgroups of $S$ of prime power order, as was suggested might be the case in some comments. The sectional $p$-rank of a finite group $G$ is the maximum over all section of $G$ which are $p$-groups, of the minimum number of generators of that section (a section of $G$ is a group of the form $H/K$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K \lhd H ).$ Hence if we define the sectional rank of $G$ to be the maximum of the minimum number of generators of an Abelian section of $G$, and denote it by $ar(G),$ then we see that for any finite group $G$, simple or not, we have $ ar(G) \leq D(G) \leq ar(G)+1.$

Comment: For finite simple groups sectional rank and the ordinary rank (the biggest rank of an abelian subgroup) almost coincide as well? 

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is there something known about $ar(S)$ for finite simple groups? 

Comment: @Mark: I am not sure.

Comment: Note that the minimum number of generators of a finite Abelian group is the maximum of the same quantity over its Sylow $p$-subgroups. The structure of Sylow $p$-subgroups of a finite simple group can be analyzed in any particular case.

Comment: Write $D'(G)$ for the sup of $D(G)$ over Sylow subgroups of $G$. That is, $D'(G)=\sup_p D_p(G)$, where $D_p(G)$ is the rank of a $p$-Sylow in $G$. So the theorem you mention says that $D(G)\in\{D'(G),D'(G)+1\}$. A natural question is whether for $G$ of Lie type relative to a prime $p$, $D'(G)$ is always (up to maybe finitely many exceptions or "bounded error") attained by precisely the $p$-Sylow of $G$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson no, you misunderstood my comment. I your example $D(G)$ is equal to $D(H)$ where $H$ is a $p$-Sylow in $G$. (The point of your example is that $D(H)$ is not equal to the rank of $H$ itself, which is smaller.) Here's an equivalent reformulation of my comment. Let $D(G)$ be the sup of ranks of all subgroups of $G$, and $D'(G)$ the sup of ranks of all subgroups of prime-power order of $G$. Is the inequality $D'(G)\le D(G)$ always an equality? (or "close" to an equality: bounded error, few exceptions, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Every finite simple group can be generated by two elements.  Except in the case of prime order, one of the elements can have order 2. See [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r32065tp23lu7847/) for example.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Andreas: Serves me right for not reading it properly.  Thanks.

Comment: but interesting nonetheless!

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody seems to have mentioned the work of Burness, Liebeck and Shalev yet:

*Burness, Timothy C.; Liebeck, Martin W.; Shalev, Aner*, [**Generation and random generation: from simple groups to maximal subgroups.**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2013.07.009), Adv. Math. 248, 59–95 (2013). [Zbl 1292.20013](https://zbmath.org/1292.20013). [PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119130941/http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/tb1u06/docs/maxgen26.pdf)

They prove that if $S$ is a non-abelian finite simple group and $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $S$ then $d(H)\leq4$. Furthermore, there are infinitely many examples that attain this bound.