# Is there a structure theorem or group law for finite groups generated by two elements?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, classification

Say that $a, b \in G$ are two elements of a finite group $G$. Is there a structure theorem for the structure of $\langle a,b\rangle$? Is there a way to derive group laws for the group operation in the generated group?

I can think of special cases (the two elements commute, one of the elements is a power of the other, the commutator of the two elements commutes with them, etc.). I am wondering if a general classification results exists, still.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a theorem of Graham Higman, Bernhard Neumann, and Hanna Neumann (*Embedding theorems for groups*, J. London Math. Society **24** (1949) 247-254) that every countable group can be embedded in a 2-generator group. This was later simplified by Bernhard and Hanna Neumann (*Embedding theorems for groups*, J. London Math. Soc. **34** (1959) 465-479). Fred Galvin has a paper in the Monthly (*Embedding Countable Groups in 2-Generator Groups*, Amer. Math. Monthly **100** no. 6 (1993), 578-580; available [from JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324618) ) giving a simple proof, showing that in fact:

> **Theorem.** Every countable group is embeddable in a 2-generator group, with one generator of order 11 and the other of order 2.

Given this, it seems hopeless to expect a structure theorem for 2-generator groups.

Comment: How about if those two generators come from a well behaved group like $SL(2, F_q)$?

Comment: The question is about finite group (not that it makes things much easier).

Comment: @TT_: As you say, it's not going to make things any easier; it still tells you that every finite group is embeddable into a 2-generated group (and I would guess one should be able to extend to proving that every finite group can be embedded into a *finite* 2-generated group).

Comment: The symmetric group on finitely many letters is generated by a `long' cycle and a transposition; therefore every finite group embeds in a 2-generated group.

Comment: Oops: `...every finite group embeds in a *finite* 2-generated group.'

Comment: Not to completely disagree with your heuristic, but every field embeds in an algebraically closed field, but the latter class is significantly easier to classify than the former.

Comment: @shane.orourke: D'oh. Of course. That's what I get for posting past 11pm...

Comment: According to Theorem 2.1 of F. Levin, Factor Groups of the Modular Group, J. London Math. Soc 43 (1968), 195-203, every countable group is embeddable in a $2$-generator group with generators of prescribed orders $p\ge3$ and $q\ge2.$