# Reference sought regarding the fact that all non-abelian finite simple groups are 2-generated

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I've learned that all non-abelian finite simple groups are $2$-generated,
i.e. have a generating set of cardinality $2$.
Is there a reference to this statement which does not just point to the
*classification of finite simple groups* in general?

Comment: The statement you've written is incorrect for the standard definition of the word "rank". Perhaps you  are thinking of the statement that *all finite simple groups can be generated by $2$ elements*?

Comment: Yes, by rank of a group I mean the smallest cardinality of a generating set of this group.

Comment: CFSG is necessary for this result. However, most cases (groups of Lie type) are covered by a single Theorem of R. Steinberg. Alternating groups are easily dealt with. Sporadic groups (by their nature) are done on an ad hoc basis.

Comment: My first comment was a bit off: you're right that the *rank of a group* has the definition that you give it. However, there are a bunch of other meanings for the word *rank* and (at least in my world), they tend to be used more (e.g. rank of a permutation group, rank of an algebraic group etc) so clarifying the definition is a good idea. In any case, as Geoff says, all known proofs of this result require CFSG. A proof without CFSG would be of great interest. (Note that with CFSG you can make even stronger statements; for instance, *all finite simple groups are $\frac32$-generated*.)

Comment: Since you want references, the $\frac32$-generation result that I mentioned can be found in Guralnick, Robert, Kantor, William, *Probalistic generation of finite simple groups*, J. Algebra 234 (2000), p. 743–792. The result was proved simultaneously by Stein, Alexander, *$1\frac12$-generation of finite simple groups*. Beiträge Algebra Geom. 39 (1998), no. 2, 349–358.

Comment: @NickGill What do you regard as the standard definition of "rank"? I try to avoid using it because it is so overused, but in my experince the most common or default intended meaning is minimal size of a generating set (as in rank of free group or free abelian group, etc.)

Comment: @DerekHolt, like I said above, the standard definition is the one the OP used so my original comment was wrong. *Mea culpa*! (Having said that, it does seem ridiculous that this single word is so overloaded with meanings, varying from context to context. Surely mathematicians could be a little more imaginative with terminology....)

Comment: Closely related question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/59213/10266

Answer (score 5):

The proof of the stronger statement that two *random* elements generate with high probability was completed by Liebeck and Shalev in:

```
Liebeck, Martin W.(4-LNDIC); Shalev, Aner(IL-HEBR-IM)
The probability of generating a finite simple group. (English summary) 
Geom. Dedicata 56 (1995), no. 1, 103–113. 
20P05 (20D06 20E18 20G40)
```

The [math review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1338320) has extensive references to work leading up to this result.