# On $(2,3)$-generation of finite simple classical groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, classical-groups

A group $G$ is called *$(a,b)$-generated* if $G=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some $x,y\in G$ with $|x|=a$ and $|y|=b$.

I know some of the histories on this problem. For example, in [this early paper in 1996](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2118584?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) Liebeck and Shalev proved that

> **Theorem.** All but finitely many finite simple classical groups other than $\operatorname{PSp}_4(2^f)$ or $\operatorname{PSp}_4(3^f)$ are $(2,3)$-generated.

In [this paper in 2017](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301839828_Generation_of_finite_simple_groups_by_an_involution_and_an_element_of_prime_order), King proved that

> **Theorem.** Every finite simple group is $(2,r)$-generated for some prime $r\ge 3$.

Is there any other result on $(2,3)$-generation or $(2,r)$-generation of finite simple classical groups? For example, the $(2,3)$-generation for low-dimensional classical groups? Or is there any lower bound (w.r.t the dimension and the order of field) of $(2,3)$-generation?

Comment: Liebeck and Shalev proved a later result that all sufficiently large-rank classical groups are $(r,s)$-generated for any two primes, at least one of which is odd. I have proved, but never got round to publishing, that all low-rank exceptional groups (up to $F_4(q)$) are $(2,p)$-generated for every odd prime $p$ dividing their order.

Comment: An interesting example is provided by ${\rm PSU}(3,3)$. This is the only non-Abelian finite simple group which can not be generated by three involutions. Consequently, ${\rm PSU}(3,3)$ is not $(2,3)$-generated, for it were generated by $a$ and $b$ with $a^{2} = b^{3} = 1$, then it would still be generated by $\{a,a^{b},a^{b^{2}}\}.$

Answer (score 3):

This is not a definitive answer (I doubt there is one), but too long for a comment.

Indeed, it is known that among the finite simple groups there are, apart from $\operatorname{PSp}_4(2^k)$, $\operatorname{PSp}_4(3^k)$ and ${}^2\mathsf{B}_2(2^{2k+1})$, only finitely many which are not (2,3)-generated. The case of classical groups was done by Liebeck and Shalev, while Lübeck and Malle dealt with the exceptional groups. The complete list of non-(2,3)-generated finite (quasi-)simple groups is not known at the moment, and it takes some effort to show for a particular group of Lie type that it is not (2,3)-generated, see, for example, [More classical groups which are not (2, 3)-generated](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-010-0217-y) by M. Vsemirnov. It is shown there that $\operatorname{PSU}_5(4)$ is not (2,3)-generated, as well as $\operatorname{Sp}_6(q)$ for any odd $q=p^k$.

Another possible direction is the study of (2,3,7)-generation, that is, whether there is a generating pair of an involution $x$ and an element $y$ of order 3, such that $xy$ is of order 7, see [Hurwitz Groups and Hurwitz Generation](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1570-7954(06)80010-0) by Tamburini and Vsemirnov.

Comment: You need to be a little careful when you start mentioning quasi-simple groups. For example, ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ ($q$ odd) is never $(2,3)$-generated, as its unique involution is central.